# Jenkins declarative pipeline mask parameter password in console logs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, password-encryption

I would like to mask the password provided as a parameter in Jenkins job and it's using the declarative pipeline syntax. I don't want to save any credentials and use them. As this will be the credentials entered by the user running the job specific to them.

I have already tried MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper, but it doesn't work. I would appreciate if someone can provide working example.

This is my Jenkinsfile for declarative pipeline using MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper which doesn't work:

```
pipeline {

    agent none

    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        skipStagesAfterUnstable()
    }

    parameters {
        string(name: 'userid', defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Enter User ID')
        password(name: 'passwd', defaultValue: 'secret', description: 'Enter Password')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            agent {
                label 'someLabel'
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[var: 'PSWD', password: params.passwd]], varMaskRegexes: []]) {
                        sh "echo PSWD: ${PSWD}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This should work. What if you remove the script?

Comment: @hakamairi I tried it without the script and same thing it fails

Comment: what's the error you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to mask the password in console logs, below is the working code:

```
pipeline {

    agent none

    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout()
        skipStagesAfterUnstable()
    }

    parameters {
        string(name: 'userid', defaultValue: 'master', description: 'Enter User ID')
        password(name: 'passwd', defaultValue: 'secret', description: 'Enter Password')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            agent {
                label 'someLabel'
            }
            steps {
                script {
                    wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: [[password: "${passwd}", var: 'PSWD']]]) {
                        sh '''echo PSWD: ${passwd}'''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```